# facebook test user no graph API search place result

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created a test user for my app under development (not public yet), and using the access token generated for the test user to call graph API.

The graph API I am trying is search place (/search type=place distance=1000).
And I specify my current location as parameter.

However, I only get the following data in return:

{"data":[]}

If I specify distance=10000, I get a few place names, but this result is totally different from my result with ordinal (non-tester) user.
Using access token for non-test-user, I get 100s or more place names.

Question:

Why this difference?
Any setting needed for test user creation so that its graph API search result is the same as the ordinal user's?
(In case it is a limitation of test user, how I can test an app which use graph API, with a test user?)

Any help or clue is highly appreciated!

Comment: Places are pages, and test users can not interact with normal pages.

Comment: In fact, looking into the test user 'Rules of Use', it was not clear if the behavior was by design.

>Test users can't Like or Follow public Facebook Pages or post on their Timeline.
>Test users can only comment on posts published by the app via a Facebook share dialog or Graph API.

So maybe I can create 100 pages (with place capability?) by this test user so that I can simulate test use-case?
The app needs facebook review (since it has features that need publish_actions permission, etc.) so as of now I need to use test-user with sandbox mode app.

Comment: You don’t need to use test users, you can also test with any normal user account that has been assigned a role in the app.

Comment: Yes, but also to test the login features that need review (publish_actions, etc.) I think we need sandboxed app and test user.

Comment: Anyway, it looks like if I generate a lot of place pages for the test user (they are invisible to normal users), I think I can test my use scenario with test user.

Comment: No, you don’t need to have the permissions reviewed to be able to test with users that have a role in the app. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_180362122361921